# Cocoa URL bookmark triggered by events

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsurl, nsfilemanager

Is it possible to listen to some notification that triggers upon file modification, such as rename or move?

Currently, I created a bookmark to a file, stored its last modified date (thanks to this great post: [Keep a reference to a file after it has moved in objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468394/keep-a-reference-to-a-file-after-it-has-moved-in-objective-c)), and then my application sets a timer that compares the bookmark's URL's last modified date, and acts upon changes.

My question is - is it possible to listen to some event, perhaps some mechanism similar to NSWorkspaceDidPerformFileOperationNotification, in order to monitor my directory's modifications, instead of using a timer?

Thanks, Nili

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish your goal:

- [NSFileCoordinator](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSFileCoordinator_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSFileCoordinator/filePresenters) together with an Object that implement [NSFilePresenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSFilePresenter_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSFilePresenter)
- [File Systems Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/FSEvents_Ref/Reference/reference.html) to listen for changes of your file or directory
- [File monitoring using Grand Central Dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355144/file-monitoring-using-grand-central-dispatch)

To watch a single file, you'll probably be most happy with NSFileCoordinator.